# Can the force of a charged particle accelarate another particle?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

By using an electric field calculator, I get that the electric field created by 1 proton within a distance of $1.39 \times 10^{-10} μ$m is $7.45 \times 10^{22}$ N/C.

[image]

Now considering another proton placed $1.39 \times 10^{-10} μ$m away from the former one, the latter one would experience a force of $7.45 \times 10^{22} \times 1.6 \times 10^{-19} = 11,920$ N, where $1.6 \times 10^{-19}$ C is the charge on a proton.

Comment: nearby to what ? how near ? Are you talking about scattering ? If so, what is the relation to the Lorentz force ?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the "nearby charged particle" and calculate the total electromagnetic force on it the same way as you did the first particle.  Given $q$, $v$, $\vec{E}$, $\vec{B}$ at that location, you know exactly the force.

Now a charge in one location may certainly affect the $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields at another location.  So the charges can interact and modify the forces on each.

But I wouldn't phrase it as the Lorentz force on one modifying the Lorentz force on another.

Comment: thanks, but how do I introduce the distance in the equation? I assume the further that nearby particle is from the other particle, the smaller the force will experience

Comment: Yes.  But maybe in that situation (if fields are otherwise weak), you don't use Lorentz but Coulomb's law directly.  If you don't already know E,B but have to calculate them it becomes more of a challenge.  For instance you can calculate it from all point charges: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefie.html#c2

Comment: thanks, I updated the question to be more specific

Comment: I assume the distance between the 2 particles is critical when it comes to calculating the effect on one another? do you think my calculations are correct?

Comment: You've changed the question to be completely different.  Generally you should just ask a new question.  See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefor.html#c1

Comment: thanks. yes, I asked and got deleted without an apparent reason. I'm aware of the Coulomb's Law. However, I assume forces would cancel. If one particle applies a force on another one due to repulsion, the other particle will decelerate from that repulsion (or to be more precise, that other particle will decelerate the ones that come after the initial particle). I'm rather trying to figure out if the Lorentz force can only be uni-directional and cause the other particle to accelerate, but never decelerate the one causing the force. As shown in the image I provided.

Comment: No.  That's like saying when two skaters push on each other they can't move because the forces cancel.  Coulomb's law says what the force is.  Whether a particle will accelerate or not depends on any other forces on it.  But 2 charges in isolation will accelerate due to Coulomb's law.

Comment: yes yes, you are right, I explained myself incorrectly. the forces don't cancel, what I meant is that one of them, if it suffers a repulsion, it will decelerate the particles coming behind it. I thought the lorentz force, from the graph I showed, only had 1 direction, but I guess the effect of the second particle on the first particle will slow down the particles (of the same charge) coming behind. Right?